# I've been trying to read from a text file and storing them into a linked list in C++

Tags: c++

so far here's what i've done

this is my header file

```
#pragma once
using namespace std;

namespace ns {
    class PersonalInfo {
    
private:
    struct personalInfo {
        int id;
        string name;
        string address;
        string country;
        int number;
        string imagePath;
        struct personalInfo* next;
    };
    personalInfo* Head;
public:
    PersonalInfo(); //constructor
    void readFile();
};
}
```

and this is my implementation.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include "Data.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace ns;

void PersonalInfo::readList() {
personalInfo* list = new personalInfo;
string temp;
try {
    ifstream info("C:\\info.txt");
    if (!info.is_open()) {
        throw "File Does Not Exist";
    }
    else {
        while (!info.eof()) {
            getline(info, temp);
            movieList->id = stoi(temp);
            getline(info, list->name);
            getline(info, list->address);
            getline(info, list->country);
            getline(info, temp);
            list->number = stoi(temp);
            getline(videos, list->imagePath);
            list->next = NULL;

            if (Head == NULL) {
                Head = list;
            }
            else
            {
                //next?
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (const char* message) {
    cerr << message << endl;
}
}
```

i'm stuck on the //next?.

i feel like i'm just making a mess at this point.

my professor said to "Use data structures, files, functions, ADTs, STLs and algorithms in your program.  Use STLs inside your ADTs" but i don't understand what they mean by that. isn't an STL a template library? or am i missing something?

i have 3 files in total: main.cpp, data.h, implementation.cpp. main contains nothing but System prints and a declaration so i can test my code.

i was recently working on a project in java so i think i'm confusing java with c++

any help is appreciated, i'm at my wits end.

edit:
sample of my text file is

```
1
Sendai 
2-chome 
japan
110 
C:\\info.jpg
2
John Douglass
2nd block
america
911
C:\\info2.jpg
...
```

Comment: Please tell us what *actually* want to do? Why would you use a linked list to store a text file?

Comment: `personalInfo* newNode = new personalInfo, * nodePtr;`. What is that??

Comment: it's a requirement for me to store them into a linked list
as for the second question
even i don't know myself, that's how my friend said i should declare it
.
i'm sorry if my english isn't the best, it's not my first language

Comment: i have to store what's inside of my txt to a linked list and be able to add a new employee remove and display.

Comment: share your txt file

Comment: sorry, i don't really know myself what i'm supposed to do.

i got to the point where i gave up and used a temporary variable to store numbers and then converted them into an integer using `getline(info, temp)` 
`newNode->id = stoi(temp)`
this way when i try to output them, it shows everything in my file correctly

Comment: sample of what's inside my txt file is
`1
Sendai
2-chome
japan
110
C:\\info.jpg`
i have by default 40 people inside my txt file.
for some reason comments doesn't show newlines sorry

Comment: you can share the sample in the post itself :)

Comment: [Why !.eof() inside a loop condition is always wrong.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/9254539)

Comment: sorry about that david, i've seen that post but i once did it on my professor's class and i got a big 0 because i didn't follow instructions

Comment: Problem is after reading last line, `.eof()` is NOT yet set, so you loop again `while (!info.eof())`,  `info >> newNode->id;` fails setting `eofbit`, but since you don't check, you blindly invoke *Undefined Behavior* in your code attempting to read from a stream with `eofbit` set. The game is over at that point. Your code could appear to operate correctly or SEGFAULT or anything in between. *It's operation is no longer defined.* You must check the stream-state after EVERY read (and you may want to look for a new professor -- this one has no clue about C++)

Comment: Further, since you are reading groups of 5-lines, you must make every read with `getline()`. Otherwise `>>` will leave the `'\n'` at the end of each line *Unread*. Your next call to `getline()` reads nothing because it found `'\n'` as the next character in the input stream and considered the input an empty-line, it extracts the `'\n'` and returns. Your next `info >> newNode->number;` fails because your line ordering is now off and you attempt to read `"japan"` into `number` setting `failbit` on the stream (which isn't checked and isn't `eofbit`) so the carnage continues....

Comment: thanks for the info! so that's why when i tried to output it it doesn't read the newline
it makes sense now.
as for my professor, i can't do anything about her, she's pretty stubborn and rarely teaches. i have to learn by copying and imitating other people which leads to ignorance, that i get. i get what pointers do but i don't know how to implement them in my own code.

Comment: Okay, give me a minute to write it up this time `:)`

Comment: Quick note as well, don’t throw a ‘const char*’, people using your API would assume that exceptions thrown would derive from ‘std::exception’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to drive yourself nuts with input errors if you don't nail down the file input aspect of filling your list. [Why !.eof() inside a loop condition is always wrong.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/9254539) (it is and it is corrupting your attempts at input).

The problem with your use of `while (!info.eof())` is after reading last line, `.eof()` is NOT yet set, so you loop again attempting, `info >> newNode->id;` which fails setting `eofbit`. However, since you don't check the stream state after each read, you invoke *Undefined Behavior* in your code continually attempting to read from a stream with `eofbit` set for `name`, `address`, `country`, `number` and `imagePath`. The game is over at that point. Your code could appear to operate correctly or SEGFAULT or anything in between. *It's operation is no longer defined*.

However, your data corruption starts with the very first six-lines of data for the very first node. Since you are reading groups of 6-lines of data for each node, you must make every read with `getline()`. Otherwise `>>` will leave the `'\n'` at the end of each line *Unread*.

Your next call to `getline()` for `name` reads nothing because it found `'\n'` as the next character in the input stream and considered the input an empty-line. `getline()` extracts the `'\n'` and returns. You then read `name` into `address`, and `address` into `country`. Your next `info >> newNode->number;` fails because ***your line ordering is now off*** and you attempt to read `"japan"` into `number` which fails setting `failbit` on the stream (which isn't checked and isn't `eofbit`) so the carnage continues... completely corrupting each node you attempt to add to your list.

C++ provides a much simpler and robust way to handle input. When working with any class or struct, you can overload the `>>` (`std::istream`) and `<<` (`std::ostream`) operators to read just what is needed to fill your `personalInfo` struct. With classes, you declare the overload as a `friend` function of the class to provide access to the private members. In your case you could declare:

```
public:
    ...
    /* overload istream for input and ostream for output */
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, PersonalInfo::personalInfo& pi);
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, PersonalInfo::personalInfo& pi);
```

and then define the `>>` operator to read and VALIDATE 6-lines of input at-a-time filling a `personalInfo` object. You would write that as:

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, PersonalInfo::personalInfo& pi)
{
    std::string id{}, name{}, address{}, country{}, number{}, imagePath{};
    
    /* validate read of six-lines of input */
    if (getline(is, id) && getline(is, name) && getline(is, address) &&
        getline(is, country) && getline(is, number) && getline(is, imagePath)) {
        
        /* convert integer values with std::stoi, initialize tmp strucct */
        PersonalInfo::personalInfo tmp { std::stoi(id), name, address, country,
                                        std::stoi(number), imagePath, nullptr };
        
        pi = tmp;   /* assign to pi reference */
    }
    
    return is;
}
```

(**note:** the `friend` keyword is only used on the declaration inside the class, not in the definition that follows if defined separately. Also note, you could assign each value to `pi.member` directly, but it was easier to just initialize a `tmp` struct and assign to `pi`)

You should add a `try {...} catch {...}` around the initialization of `tmp` above to catch and handle any error in the conversion of `std::stoi(id)` or `std::stoi(number)`. If a failure in conversion occurs, you would want to set `failbit` for the stream state of `is` above so the read loop terminates at the first failure and does not attempt to add the invalid data. You can use `is.setstate (std::ios_base::failbit);` to set `failbit` on the stream in the `catch` portion of your [try-block](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch). I'll leave that to you.

(see the example at the link above, essentially you just wrap the initialization of `tmp` and assignment to `pi` in the `try` portion and output an error setting `failbit` in the `catch` clause)

With the overload defined, you simply loop reading a `personalInfo` object at a time and adding it to your linked list, e.g.

```
void PersonalInfo::readFile()
{
    if (filename.empty()) { /* validate filename not empty */
        std::cerr << "error: readFile() - filename empty.\n";
        return;
    }
    
    PersonalInfo::personalInfo tmp{};   /* temporary struct to fill */
    std::ifstream f(filename);          /* open file */
    
    if (!f.is_open()) { /* validate file open for reading */
        std::cerr << "error: readFile() - file open failed " << filename << '\n';
        return;
    }
    
    while (f >> tmp)    /* read six lines at a time filling tmp  */
        add (tmp);      /* allocate and initialize node with tmp */
}
```

The `add()` function just isolates the allocation and initialization of the node and adding it in-order to your list. You can do it all in `readFile()`, but I find it cleaner to not combine the I/O `readFile()` with the list-operation `add()`, e.g.

```
bool PersonalInfo::add (const PersonalInfo::personalInfo& pi)
{
    /* allocate and initialize node */
    PersonalInfo::personalInfo *node = new PersonalInfo::personalInfo;
    *node = pi;
    
    if (!Head)                  /* add to list */
        Head = Tail = node;
    else {
        Tail->next = node;
        Tail = node;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

(**note:** `Tail` always points to the last node in the list allowing adding nodes to the end of the list in O(1) time. For the first node, both `Head` and `Tail` point to the first node. Thereafter, you simply update `Tail->next` to the address of the new node and then reset `Tail` to that address)

To output (print) your list you do much the same overloading the `<<` operator so it outputs one node in your list, e.g.

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, PersonalInfo::personalInfo& pi)
{
    os  << "\nid        : " << pi.id << '\n'
        << "name      : " << pi.name << '\n'
        << "address   : " << pi.address << '\n'
        << "country   : " << pi.country << '\n'
        << "number    : " << pi.number << '\n'
        << "imagePath : " << pi.imagePath << '\n';
    
    return os;
}
```

You can change the formatting of the output to anything you like. A simple `prnList()` function that simply iterates over each node in the list outputting each node can be written as:

```
void PersonalInfo::prnList()
{
    PersonalInfo::personalInfo *iter = Head;
    
    while (iter) {
        std::cout << *iter;
        iter = iter->next;
    }
}
```

Avoid using *MagicNumbers* and hardcoding filenames in your code. You shouldn't have to recompile just to read from a different filename. Provide the filename to your object as part of the constructor. You can use a single constructor and provide an empty filename if none is given when the class is constructed. (You would just need to write another member function, a "setter" function to set the filename). You can write the constructor as follows:

```
     PersonalInfo (std::string fname="") { Head = Tail = nullptr; filename = fname; }
```

Which optionally takes a `std::string` argument for the filename, initializing `filename` empty if none is provided.

`main()` takes arguments. That is what `int argc, char **argv` are for. A simple way of providing the filename to read is just to provide it as the first argument to your program and use `argv[1]` to initialize the `filename` in your `PersonalInfo` class when you declare it. That makes setting the filename when you create the class as simple as:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "error: insufficient input\n"
                     "usage: ./program filename\n";
        return 1;
    }
    
    PersonalInfo P { argv[1] };
    P.readFile();
    P.prnList();
}
```

I'll have to look back and see if there are other major points that need addressing. Putting it altogether, a short example implementation of your list would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class PersonalInfo {
    
private:
    struct personalInfo {
        int id;
        std::string name;
        std::string address;
        std::string country;
        int number;
        std::string imagePath;
        struct personalInfo* next;
    };
    personalInfo *Head, *Tail;      /* add Tail pointer for O(1) in-order insertion */
    std::string filename;
    
public:
    PersonalInfo (std::string fname="") { Head = Tail = nullptr; filename = fname; }
    /* overload istream for input and ostream for output */
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, PersonalInfo::personalInfo& pi);
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, PersonalInfo::personalInfo& pi);
    /* add to allocate and intialize each node */
    bool add (const PersonalInfo::personalInfo& pi);
    void readFile();
    void prnList();
};

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, PersonalInfo::personalInfo& pi)
{
    std::string id{}, name{}, address{}, country{}, number{}, imagePath{};
    
    /* validate read of six-lines of input */
    if (getline(is, id) && getline(is, name) && getline(is, address) &&
        getline(is, country) && getline(is, number) && getline(is, imagePath)) {
        
        /* convert integer values with std::stoi, initialize tmp strucct */
        PersonalInfo::personalInfo tmp { std::stoi(id), name, address, country,
                                        std::stoi(number), imagePath, nullptr };
        
        pi = tmp;   /* assign to pi reference */
    }
    
    return is;
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, PersonalInfo::personalInfo& pi)
{
    os  << "\nid        : " << pi.id << '\n'
        << "name      : " << pi.name << '\n'
        << "address   : " << pi.address << '\n'
        << "country   : " << pi.country << '\n'
        << "number    : " << pi.number << '\n'
        << "imagePath : " << pi.imagePath << '\n';
    
    return os;
}

bool PersonalInfo::add (const PersonalInfo::personalInfo& pi)
{
    /* allocate and initialize node */
    PersonalInfo::personalInfo *node = new PersonalInfo::personalInfo;
    *node = pi;
    
    if (!Head)                  /* add to list */
        Head = Tail = node;
    else {
        Tail->next = node;
        Tail = node;
    }
    
    return true;
}

void PersonalInfo::readFile()
{
    if (filename.empty()) { /* validate filename not empty */
        std::cerr << "error: readFile() - filename empty.\n";
        return;
    }
    
    PersonalInfo::personalInfo tmp{};   /* temporary struct to fill */
    std::ifstream f(filename);          /* open file */
    
    if (!f.is_open()) { /* validate file open for reading */
        std::cerr << "error: readFile() - file open failed " << filename << '\n';
        return;
    }
    
    while (f >> tmp)    /* read six lines at a time filling tmp  */
        add (tmp);      /* allocate and initialize node with tmp */
}

void PersonalInfo::prnList()
{
    PersonalInfo::personalInfo *iter = Head;
    
    while (iter) {
        std::cout << *iter;
        iter = iter->next;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "error: insufficient input\n"
                     "usage: ./program filename\n";
        return 1;
    }
    
    PersonalInfo P { argv[1] };
    P.readFile();
    P.prnList();
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your sample data in the file named `dat/personalinfo.txt`, you would run the program as follows receiving the following output:

```
$ ./bin/ll_personalinfo dat/personalinfo.txt

id        : 1
name      : Sendai
address   : 2-chome
country   : japan
number    : 110
imagePath : C:\\info.jpg

id        : 2
name      : John Douglass
address   : 2nd block
country   : america
number    : 911
imagePath : C:\\info2.jpg
```

The key in all of this is to nail down your input routine. Validate all six-lines are read and that every member of `personalInfo` is filled before considering the input valid. You should also enclose ech `std::stoi()` conversion in a `try {..} catch {..}` block to catch any errors during conversion to `int`. That I leave that to you.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: thank you so much for your help david. will take this as a mental note!

Comment: If you can't wrap your head around the overload of `<<` and `>>` you can just move the code from `>> ` to  `readFile()` inside the `while` loop  and do the same thing there. However reading all 6 lines with `getline()` is the way to go. Otherwise you will need to call `.ignore()` after ever call using the non-overloaded `>> ` for `id` and `number` to consume the `'\n'` (and any other stray characters) left in `stdin`. You can also move the `add()` code into `readFile()`, but then the `readFile()` function is horribly busy and not long just a `readFile()` function.